# Efficient access to file notes

Tags: linux-mint, filesystems, nautilus

Recently, I started using the "Notes" that one can assign to files. They can be found by right-clicking on the file -> `Properties` -> tab "`Notes`". See the following image:
[image: The "Properties" of my file screenshot_2021-11-16_09-09.png]

I would like to work more with these file notes. Particularly when the file is an image that I create for school or the like, then I would like to capture some buzzwords in the notes. This way, I can recall quickly what the content is, without staring at it for a long time -- actually even without looking at the image.
My operating system is Linux Mint 20.2.

The first question is: Is this the intended use-case for the notes assigned to a file? If not, what is a recommended practice?
Second question (if answer to first question is Yes): How can I make access to the notes quicker? Ideally, there would be an option to show thumbnails of the image on the left and the notes on the right hand side of File Browser; clicking on the notes opens an editor for the notes (as shown in the image above, for example). Even more ideally: I can enable this option folder-wise.

I couldn't find configurations concerning the notes in the `File Management Preferences`.

**Edit:**
In the Desktop User Guide, I found this information:

> To add a note to a file or folder, perform the following steps:
>
> 1. Open the file or folder to which you want to add a note in the view pane.
> 2. Choose Notes from the drop-down list at the top of the side pane. To display the side pane, choose View ▸ Side Pane.
> 3. Type the note in the side pane. A note emblem is added to the file or folder in the view pane, and a note icon is added to the side pane. You can click on this icon to display the note.
>
> To delete a note, delete the note text from Notes in the side pane.

You can find this text under `To Add a Note Using Notes in the Side Pane` in the `Desktop User Guide`.
It seems to be a step in the right direction, but when I open the side pane as described, the drop-down doesn't contain `Notes`.

Comment: A big warning as remark: The "Notes" are metadata stored in `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-<UUID OF PARTITION>` and ONLY copied/moved when you use nautilus or another `gio`-compatible browser or `gio` as CLI command.

Comment: Untested, but seems to add the option of making tabs one of the columns in list view: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/02/nautilus-exif-pdf-and-audio-metadata.html

Comment: @FelixJN uff! That seems to be a pretty dangerous feature then.. imagine I nautilus to annotate a lot of files, then put them in a tar/zip/… archive and store that, expecting the comments to persist. or one afternoon I just decide to use thunar or the kde file manager or `mv` to rename files.